# Can't sort C# DataGridView column as integers

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a `DataGridView gridFilas` in my windows form application with two columns and the second column always contains strings that can be converted to integers. When I click to sort it, it is sorted as strings resulting in something like:

`1, 11, 2, 22`

But I need it to be sorted as integers, like:

`1, 2, 11, 22`

I've already tried all the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921470/sorting-numerically-in-a-datagridviewtextboxcolumn) but none worked, btw the accepted answer, it didn't worked because the `SortCompare` event wasn't being fired because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365573/2414842).

So what I've tried so far is adding a `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` and sort it with:

```
private void gridFilas_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

    // this for loop has been added in a vain hope of converting all elements to integer to see if it works...
    for (int i = 0; i < gridFilas.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string v = gridFilas.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        gridFilas.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(v);
    }

    if (queuesSortedAscending)
    {
        gridFilas.Sort(gridFilas.Columns["Tamanho_Fila"], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }
    else
    {
        gridFilas.Sort(gridFilas.Columns["Tamanho_Fila"], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
    queuesSortedAscending = !queuesSortedAscending;

}
```

The datasource is set on the creation (the constructor of the `Form`) with:

```
dsComponentes = new DataSet();
// ... more code 
gridFilas.DataSource = dsComponentes.Tables["Queue"];
```

Whenever I add a new line to the DataSource I assure it is parsed to int:

```
DataRow qlinha = dsComponentes.Tables["Queue"].NewRow();
qlinha["Nome_Fila"] = process;
qlinha["Tamanho_Fila"] = Int32.Parse(status);
dsComponentes.Tables["Queue"].Rows.Add(qlinha);
```

I've also tried changing the data type of the column beforehand:

```
dsComponentes.Tables["Queue"].Columns["Tamanho_Fila"].DataType = typeof(int);
```

So, I don't know what else to do, I just need to order it as integers not strings. Any solution is welcome.

Comment: `the second column always contains strings that can be converted to integers`  DGV columns are typed - use a column of integers *or* a Custom Sorter that used a Natural Sort.  Gobs of docs and posts on both topics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never show where you're creating the `DataTable` that you're binding to (`dsComponentes.Tables["Queue"]`), but when you add that column you should be able to indicate that it's an `int`.

```csharp
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(int));
```

This will cause the bound `DataGridView` to sort that column as integers.

It looks like there is a `DataType` in the Columns Collection Editor as well, if you're using the designer to create your `DataSet`. You can set the type to `System.Int32` on that column and it will sort as you expect.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
   static class Program
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// The main entry point for the application.
      /// </summary>
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

         var frm = new Form()
         {
            Text = "Data Grid View Form",
            Name = "DataGridViewForm",
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400)
         };
         var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

         var dataTable = new DataTable();
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
         dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

         dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
         dataTable.Columns.Add("IdAsString", typeof(string));
         var r1 = dataTable.NewRow();
         r1["Id"] = 1;
         r1["IdAsString"] = "1";
         dataTable.Rows.Add(r1);

         var r2 = dataTable.NewRow();
         r2["Id"] = 11;
         r2["IdAsString"] = "11";
         dataTable.Rows.Add(r2);

         var r3 = dataTable.NewRow();
         r3["Id"] = 2;
         r3["IdAsString"] = "2";
         dataTable.Rows.Add(r3);

         var r4 = dataTable.NewRow();
         r4["Id"] = 22;
         r4["IdAsString"] = "22";
         dataTable.Rows.Add(r4);

         frm.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

         Application.Run(frm);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to use a nuget package: [Equin ApplicationFramework BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView)

It is very similar to a standard .net BindingList, except that it contains functions to sort.

- Import the BindingListView nuget into your project
- Use Visual Studio designer to create your form
- Use the toolbox to add a BindingSource to your form
- Go to the properties of this BindingSource, select DataSource, Add Project Data Source, select Object and add the class of items that you want to show in your DataGridView
- Now use the toolbox to add your DataGridView
- In the properties of the DataGridView choose the BindingSource as the datasource.

Now all public properties of your class will be shown as column in the DataGridView. Edit the columns accordingly: remove the columns that you won't use.

In my example I will sort a sequence of Persons:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

Go to your Form1 class. We'll add a BindingListView from the nuget package as a member.
In the constructor we'll assign this to the bindingsource that is assigned to the DataGridView.

```
class Form
{
    // the BindingListView from the nuget package:
    private readonly BindingListView<Person> sortableBindingListView;

    // constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // make sure there is a Components Container, that will dispose
        // the components upon disposal of the form
        if (this.components == null)
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }

        // construct the sortable BindingListView for Persons:
        this.sortableBindingListView = new BindingListView<Person>(this.components);

        // create some Persons:
        var persons = new Person[]
        {
            new Person{Id = 1, Name = "F", BirthDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)},
            new Person{Id = 2, Name = "A", BirthDate = new DateTime(1998, 4, 7)},
            new Person{Id = 3, Name = "C", BirthDate = new DateTime(2011, 3, 8)},
            new Person{Id = 4, Name = "Z", BirthDate = new DateTime(1997, 2, 3)},
            new Person{Id = 5, Name = "K", BirthDate = new DateTime(2003, 9, 5)},
        };

        // Assign the DataSources:
        this.sortableBindingListView.DataSource = persons;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.sortableBindingListView;
    }
}
```

This is enough to get your sorting working. You don't have to add anything extra. Upon clicking the columns the column is filtered.

Some interesting functions:

```
private Person SelectedPerson
{
    get {return ((ObjectView<Person>)this.SortableBindingSource.Current)?.Object; }
}

private void DisplayPersons (IEnumerable<Person> personsToDisplay)
{
    this.SortableBindingSource.DataSource = personsToDisplay.ToList();
    this.SortableBindingSource.Refresh(); // this will update the DataGridView
}

private IEnumerable<Person> DisplayedPersons
{
    get {return this.SortableBindingSource; }
    // BindingListview<T> implements IEnumerable<T>
}
```

This is all. You don't need to create special functions to sort on mouse clicks. The sorting will be done automatically inclusive deciding on the sort order and displaying the correct sorting glyphs.

If you want to sort programmatically:

```
// sort columnPropertyA in descending order:
this.SortableBindingSource.Sort(this.columnPropertyA.ListsortDirection.Descending);
```

One of the nice things about the BindingListView is the filtering option:

```
// show only items where Name not null:
this.SortableBindingSource.ApplyFilter(person => person.Name != null);

// remove the filter:
this.SortableBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
```

I'm not sure if a Refresh() is needed after applying or removing a filter.